# how to create symbolic link (ln) between two partitions

Tags: ubuntu, symbolic-link, hardlink

I have two partitions on my Ubuntu 10.04.3 server.

```
partition 1: /mnt/storage/  
partition 2: /var/www/myweb/
```

now when i run the following command

```
$ ln /mnt/storage/sourcefile.txt /var/www/myweb/linkedfile.txt
```

i got this

```
ln: creating hard link `/var/www/myweb/linkedfile.txt' => `sourcefile.txt': Invalid cross-device link
```

any idea of how to make this symbolic link??

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot use hard links across file systems like that. You need to use `ln -s` to create a symbolic link.

```
ln -s /mnt/storage/sourcefile.txt /var/www/myweb/linkedfile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ ln -s /mnt/storage/sourcefile.txt /var/www/myweb/linkedfile.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

type **pwd** in the terminal in the containing folder
and take the full path of your partition
then put it in

```
$ ln -s fullpath/sourcefile.txt fullpath/linkedfile.txt
```

then move the link to the destination partition